# How does compiler understand, according to which template need to unpack the parameters pack?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to deal with variadic templates in C++, and I have a  question. How does compiler understand, how it should unpack the parameters pack in templates? Look at the code, please.

How does compiler "bites off" the head of tuple in **get** method?
How does compliler unpack Tail... as Head and Tail... ?
It is not clear for me.

```
template<typename... Args>
struct tuple;

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct tuple<Head, Tail...> : tuple<Tail...>
{
        // How does compliler unpack Tail... as Head and Tail... ?
    tuple(Head h, Tail... tail) 
        : tuple<Tail...>(tail...), head_(h)
    {}
    typedef tuple<Tail...> base_type;
    typedef Head           value_type;

    base_type& base = static_cast<base_type&>(*this);
    Head       head_;
};

template<>
struct tuple<>
{};

template<int I, typename Head, typename... Args>
struct getter
{
    typedef typename getter<I - 1, Args...>::return_type return_type;
    static return_type get(tuple<Head, Args...> t)
    {
        //How does compiler "bites off" the head of tuple here?
        return getter<I - 1, Args...>::get(t);
    }
};

template<typename Head, typename... Args>
struct getter<0, Head, Args...>
{
    typedef typename tuple<Head, Args...>::value_type return_type;
    static return_type get(tuple<Head, Args...> t)
    {
        return t.head_;
    }
};

template<int I, typename Head, typename... Args>
typename getter<I, Head, Args...>::return_type
get(tuple<Head, Args...> t)
{
    return getter<I, Head, Args...>::get(t);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for template overload resolution are quite ...complicated. And that's an understatement. The following explanation is limited specifically to the shown code.

A compiler simply tries matching a template invocation with all available (overloaded) template declarations. The rules for selecting a template, when more than ones match get quite ...complicated. But in this case there's always only one possible match in `std::tuple` template's case. `std::get` does involve some overload resolution, but it's better to start off by unraveling how `std::tuple` itself works, so you understand the process.

So, you're plopped down the following in your code:

```
std::tuple<int, char, float>
```

The compiler looks at the two templates:

```
template<typename Head, typename... Tail> struct tuple<Head, Tail...>

template<> struct tuple;
```

Those are the only two possibilities. And, obviously, only the first one matches, if `Head` gets "assigned" to `int`, and `...Tail` gets "assigned" to `char, float`. That's the only way to match this template invocation.

This template then gets declared in this manner. The resulting class then inherits from

```
std::tuple<int, float>
```

And then same process repeats itself again. The resulting class has `Head` "assigned" to `int`, and `...Tail` "assigned" to `float`. Lather, rinse, repeat.

On the next step down the ladder, `Head` is `float`, and `...Tail` is an empty parameter pack. The resulting class inherits from `std::tuple<>`, therefore, and on the next and the final step it's the `std::tuple<>` specialization, for the empty parameter pack, that gets used.

The situation with `get()` is slightly more complicated, but it's the same basic process, and once you understand the `std::tuple` example it'll help you to understand what's going on here, a little bit better.

A `std::get`() on the empty `std::tuple` is never valid. Therefore, `std::get` itself is just a specialization on a non-empty `std::tuple`'s variadic template argument:

```
template<int I, typename Head, typename... Args>
typename getter<I, Head, Args...>::return_type
get(tuple<Head, Args...> t)
{
    return getter<I, Head, Args...>::get(t);
}
```

This process, once again, starts off with `Head` getting assigned to  the first type, and remaining types assigned to the variadic `...Args`.

What this all comes down is `std::getter` peeling off each layer of the `std::tuple` onion until the index `I` reaches 0, indicating you've arrived at the selected layer in the `std::tuple` onion. You start off with the main template itself:

```
template<int I, typename Head, typename... Args> struct getter
```

and a specialization when `I` is 0:

```
template<typename Head, typename... Args> struct getter<0, Head, Args...>
```

When you invoke `std::get<1>`, `I` starts off as 1, `Head` as `int`, and `...Args` as `float, char`. This is matched by the generic template, which pretty much delegates its `get()` to `getter<0, float, char>`.

And the next layer onion gets matched and implemented by the specialization.